# How to iterate feature files in cucumber selenium

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I want to enter 5 different dates in my application.For that i am storing those dates in feature files.I want to iterate all dates one by one

```
Feature File:
Scenario Outline: To test feature file iteration   
Given User is on login Screen
When user enters credentials "<User_ID>" and "<Password>"
Then user enters "<processing_date>"
And clicks on logout  
Examples:

| User_ID | Password |processing_date|
| Abc     | Abc.     |28/11/2018|
| Abc.    | Abc.     |03/12/2018|
```

```
Method for entering date:
```

```
public void date(DataTable date) throws Exception {             
List<List<String>> data = processing_date.asList(String.class);//I had to use asList as .raw was not available)
System.out.println("Size is :" +data.size() );
for(int i=1;i<data.size();i++) 
{
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    String scriptText = "document.querySelector('.datafield').setAttribute('value','" + date.get(i).get(i)+ "')";
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(scriptText);
    log.info("date is entered");
}
```

```
But this is not working.Is there any method to iterate feature files.Getting error as Argument mismatch.If i change DataTable date to String date and remove for loop , it works fine.But every time it login and logouts.But i want to execute all 5 dates one after the other without logging out.
```

Comment: Show you whole scenario in the question please

Comment: I have updated the comment

Answer (score 0):

You are using a scenario outline. You need to understand how a scenario outline works. Basically a scenario outline is a compact way of writing several separate scenarios. So your outline will create a single scenario for each date in your examples table. This means your step will only have one date available so there is nothing to iterate over.